# Generating product feeds URL in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.3

I would like to know if Magento has any native product feeds generator (I mean in the backend). I need the feeds to be generated in a URL, not physical files, since they will be automatically called every hour. Shopware has a product feeds section, this is why I am wodering about Magento.

In case there is no such option, I was searching for any free extension or extensions which would do it correctly, but couldn't find any.

The feeds are needed for Google Merchant, Facebook Ads and Belboon.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: thanks for the advic for using the indicated forum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Followed these below links regarding generating product feeds

1- https://www.demacmedia.com/magento-commerce/magento-tutorials/magento-data-feed/

2- http://www.cpcstrategy.com/blog/2013/06/magento-feed-exporter-how-to-use/

Answer (score 1):

Magento has a built in RSS feed generator:

https://magenticians.com/add-rss-feed-to-magento/